# How do you add a variable to an excel function?

Tags: excel, variables, excel-formula

I have an excel file with multiple sheets. I reference data in sheet 2 like:

`=sheet1!A1,`

I would like to use a variable to change the function based on a value entered in cell x on sheet2 . I tried:

`=sheet1!"x"1`

to try and change all formulas based on entering a value for x. This didn't work because excel thought I was referencing something in sheet 1. I can't do this with VB due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the indirect() function:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!" & A1 & "1")
```

Where A1 is the cell in which you find "x".

Comment: @xorn glad to hear it,  Please come back in a few minutes and mark it correct by clicking the green/gray check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is by using 
 `=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!" & A1 & "1")`

EDIT: Dang I'm too slow, Scott is like lightning.